# cakephp SQL error at $this->User->saveField()

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

When I try to update a user, let's say his account balance

```
$this->User->id = $validUserId;
$this->User->saveField('balance', 100);
```

I get this error

```
SQL Error: 1054: Unknown column 'User.group_id' in 'field list'
```

with this automatically generated query druring the save process

```
SELECT `User`.`group_id` FROM `users` AS `User`   WHERE `User`.`id` = *validUserId*    LIMIT 1
```

The user belongsTo a UserGroup and therefore the user has user_group_id attribute, is there any way to tell cake, that the attribute is related to a UserGroup?

Thanks in advance,
EL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe, if you are just saving a field, you don't need to do validations. In that case just do

```
$this->User->saveField('balance', 100, false);
```

http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelsaveField

Or if there is a callback like beforeSave or something, I think you can do something like:

```
$this->save($data, array('validate'=>false, 'callbacks'=>false));
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Most certainly, the models should look like this:

```
class UserGroup extends AppModel {
  var $belongsTo = array(
    'UserGroup' => array(
      'className' => 'UserGroup',
      'foreignKey' => 'user_group_id'
    )
  );
}

class User extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array(
    'User' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'foreignKey' => 'user_group_id'
    )
  );
}
```

Read about associating CakePHP models in the [book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together)

Comment: are you suer UserGroup belongsTo UserGroup and User hasMany Users? My model is fine...User belongsTo UserGroup, foreign key set to user_group_id and UserGroup hasMany Users, with the same FK